# Grid respect an image centered

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I would like to position an evenly spaced grid over an image using tikzpicture.

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[table]{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Grid respect image}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture, shift={(current page.center)}]
    \node (photo) [anchor=south west, inner sep=0pt] at (0,0) {\includegraphics[height=6cm]{image.jpg}};
    \begin{scope}[x={(photo.south east)}, y={(photo.north west)}]
        \draw[help lines, step=0.1, line width=0.5mm, color=red] (0.0,0.0) grid (1.0,1.0);
    \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

This code will return the following image:

[image]

as you can see the image is positioned in the upper right side of the canvas, due to `anchor=south west`.

If I replace `anchor=south west` with `anchor=center` it will return an error `Arithmetic overflow` but I don't understand why.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try to change the step value? With a random image I obtained a correct spacing with 0.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forget to shift the origin of your scope:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Grid respect image}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture, shift={(current page.center)}]
    \node (photo) [anchor=center, inner sep=0pt] at (0,0) {\includegraphics[height=6cm]{example-image}};
    \begin{scope}[shift={(photo.south west)},x={(photo.south east)}, y={(photo.north west)}]
      \draw[help lines, step=0.1, line width=0.5mm, color=red] (0.0,0.0) grid (1.0,1.0);
    \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for all the answers, are very useful.

Answer (score 5):

I think the problem with your code appears because you change the origin and `[x={(photo.south east)}, y={(photo.north west)}]` doesn't work as expected. But don't trust on me.

As an alternative, following code works:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Grid respect image}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
    \node[outer sep=0pt, inner sep=0pt] (photo) at (current page.center) {\includegraphics[height=6cm]{example-image}};
 \begin{scope}
        \foreach \i in {0,.2,...,1}{
            \draw ($(photo.south west)!\i!(photo.south east)$)--
            ($(photo.north west)!\i!(photo.north east)$);
            \draw ($(photo.south west)!\i!(photo.north west)$)--
            ($(photo.south east)!\i!(photo.north east)$);}
    \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Remove all explicit positioning of image in your MWE and use simple `\centering` for centering of image and draw grid relative to image:

```
\documentclass[table]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Grid respect image}
\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=0pt]
\node (photo) {\includegraphics[height=6cm]{example-image}};
\draw[line width=0.5mm, color=red] (photo.south west) grid (photo.north east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

gives:

[image]

Comment: How about drawing  a grid with 10 steps on x direction and 10 steps on y direction?

Comment: with change of step size. in this particular image size with `ystep=0.6,xstep=0.8`. In general, with unknown image size, you need first to measure image size and than calculate step size.

Answer (score 2):

This addition to  @Zarko's answer you need to define step like this `step=1/10` 
or `xstep=1/8` and `ystep=1/9` if you need 8 steps on x-direction, and 9 steps on y-direction

```
\documentclass[table]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Grid respect image}

\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (photo) [anchor=south west,inner sep=0pt] {\includegraphics[height=6cm]{example-image}};
    \begin{scope}[x={(photo.south east)},y={(photo.north west)}]
     \draw[step=1/10, line width=0.5mm, color=red] (0,0) grid (1,1);
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]